# Robot position flashing rviz using rtabmap

Tags: navigation, kinect, roomba, ros-kinetic, create-autonomy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When using rtabmap somehow my robot position starts to flash. It will flash extremely quick between several positions.
Also this impacts it drive ability.
This could be due to more locations being possible?
I am using an roomba with the create_autonomy package with an kinect on top of it.
It will reach a goal but will take a weird route to do so.

output ROSwtf

> Found 2 error(s).

> ERROR The following nodes should be connected but aren't:

- /move_base_node->/move_base_node (/move_base_node/global_costmap/footprint)
- /move_base_node->/move_base_node (/move_base_node/local_costmap/footprint)

> ERROR TF multiple authority contention:

- node [/rtabmap/rtabmap] publishing transform [odom] with parent [map] already published by node [/slam_gmapping]
- node [/slam_gmapping] publishing transform [odom] with parent [map] already published by node [/rtabmap/rtabmap]

EDIT: When disabling gmapping roswtf will not give me the error anymore. There is only one more problem that. When setting /rtabmap/grid_map as my map topic in the global costmap it will no longer react to any goals send to the robot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248545/robot-position-flashing-rviz-using-rtabmap/) by [gijsje170](https://answers.ros.org/users/25135/gijsje170/) on ROS Answers with karma: 171 on 2016-11-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fsteinhardt](https://answers.ros.org/users/4889/fsteinhardt/) on 2016-11-25**:
Does roswtf show any problems?

**Comment by [gijsje170](https://answers.ros.org/users/25135/gijsje170/) on 2016-11-25**:
edited main question with the errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Like @matlabbe said, it sounds like an issue with the TF tree.

There may be odometry issues if you are using a Roomba 700 series or later with **create_autonomy**. Please refer to [this issue](https://github.com/AutonomyLab/create_autonomy/issues/32) for a potential fix.

---

Originally posted by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) with karma: 1870 on 2016-11-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gijsje170](https://answers.ros.org/users/25135/gijsje170/) on 2016-11-25**:
Hi that is actually my own issue :P It reduces the flashing but when traveling longer distance the flashing will increase.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

It looks like that you may have more than one node publishing the same TF, which would cause flickering between both. Make sure that there are not multiples nodes publishing the same transforms in TF tree, e.g., `/map -> /odom` or `/odom -> /base_link`.

cheers

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2016-11-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gijsje170](https://answers.ros.org/users/25135/gijsje170/) on 2016-11-25**:
When looking at my TF tree i see a link from map to odom and also a link from odom to base_footprint but there should be a link right? there is only 1 arrow each time so the TF looks correct. I know it has to do with rtabmap since when not using rtabmap it works without